# Find the length of base of a triangle without using Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: calculus

I'm curious whether it is possible to find the length of base of the triangle without using Pythagorean Theorem

No Pythagorean Theorem mean:

=> No trigonometric because trigonometric is built on top of Pythagorean Theorem.
etc $\sin{\theta} = \frac{a}{r}$

=> No Integration on line or curve because the integration is built on top of Pythagorean Theorem.
etc: $s(x) = \int \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + 1}$

[image]

Comment: What information is given?

Comment: There are three similar right triangles. Is $a=a_1$ or not?

Comment: Yep, a = a_1, it has to be

Comment: Do you know you can edit an object in Geogebra so that it is labeled with something different from its name? That is, you can make the line segment named $a_1$ be displayed with the label "a" so that you have two line segments labeled with the same symbol.

Comment: Oh.. I did not know that.. this is why I have a and a_1 in my figure.. LOL.. thanks for pointing that out..

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to construct this figure in a way such that
$a_1 \neq a.$

But in the case where $a_1 = a,$ we can observe that the perpendicular line labeled $g$ divides the large triangle into two congruent triangles,
hence the triangle with hypotenuse $AB$ is twice the area of the triangle with hypotenuse $a.$

The larger triangle also is similar to the smaller triangle.
In order to have twice the area, all its dimensions, including the length of the hypotenuse, must therefore be greater by a factor of $\sqrt2.$

A somewhat more complicated version of this argument can be applied in the case where $a_1 \neq a,$ resulting in a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem.
I would argue that *proving* the Pythagorean Theorem is technically not the same thing as *using* it but would still be a violation of the spirit of the question. Proving only the special case $a_1 = a,$ however, does not rise to the level of a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem (which is more general).

Comment: Nice.. similar triangle solve it.. nice... but I think my question is not general enough... If I given right triangle a and b, find the hypotenuse.. then it is my whole objective of my question

Comment: @bsdshell You probably should not have labeled the left leg $a_1$ and written $a_1=a$ in a comment if you meant to set a problem in which a right triangle has legs $a$ and $b$, not necessarily equal. Also, if you really meant a general right triangle, then marty cohen's answer applies. The length of the hypotenuse is the square root of the sum of the squares of the other two sides; no matter how we spin it, any solution will be a proof of $a^2+b^2=c^2.$ So the question is essentially, "Solve for $X$ in general without using a general solution for $X$."

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB^2=a^2+a_1^2$, any derivation of the length of
$AB$, if it does not use the Pythagorean theorem must essentially be a proof of the Pythagorean theorem.

There are so many proofs of the theorem that there seems to be an infinite number since no matter how many you find there is always one more.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question. You do not allow use Pythagorean Theorem, it means you are not allow to prove Pythagorean Theorem and use it in the question. What I'm looking for something is something is "new" without using Pythagorean Theorem. Many theorems and technique are built on top of Pythagorean Theorem in High school and College level math.